# What's the best way to work with permissions in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 4 project I would like to work with permissions, which I get from an API. Permissions are saved as array with ids. Some single elements like user or blog post have property with allowed permissions, which allow or not allow actions like edit or delete, as array with ids.

What's the best way to check and to handle permissions in Angular 4 projects? Has Angular some out of the bos solutions for permissions handling? Can somebody give me ideas for realization of permissions handling, if Angular doesn't have some out of the box solution?

Comment: Permissions are like Guards , You can take a look at guards for components in Angular [Guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)Also you can take a look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

like Rahul comment says the one solution out of the box is more likely what you want are `Guard` ..

Remember guard are only for ROUTING .. so only to check if a user can access a route or not .. but not to display single element in a component based on roles or whatever .. for that i suggest to you to use `*ngIf` or show to render/display or not some UI elements ...

For one Guard based on Roles (not only if use is auth or not) ..you can do something like:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService, CurrentUserService } from "app/shared/services";
import { Router, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate } from "@angular/router";
import { AspNetUsersDTO } from "app/shared/models";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
        private _currentUser: CurrentUserService,
        private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {

            if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
                resolve(false);
                return;
            }


            var currentUser: AspNetUsersDTO = new AspNetUsersDTO();

            this._currentUser.GetCurrentUser().then((resp) => {
                currentUser = resp;
                let userRole = currentUser.roles && currentUser.roles.length > 0 ? currentUser.roles[0].toUpperCase() : '';
                let roles = route && route.data["roles"] && route.data["roles"].length > 0 ? route.data["roles"].map(xx => xx.toUpperCase()) : null;

                if (roles == null || roles.indexOf(userRole) != -1) resolve(true);
                else {
                    resolve(false);
                    this.router.navigate(['login']);
                }

            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
            });
        });

    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {

            if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
                resolve(false);
                return;
            }


            var currentUser: AspNetUsersDTO = new AspNetUsersDTO();

            this._currentUser.GetCurrentUser().then((resp) => {
                currentUser = resp;
                let userRole = currentUser.roles && currentUser.roles.length > 0 ? currentUser.roles[0].toUpperCase() : '';
                let roles = route && route.data["roles"] && route.data["roles"].length > 0 ? route.data["roles"].map(xx => xx.toUpperCase()) : null;

                if (roles == null || roles.indexOf(userRole) != -1) resolve(true);
                else {
                    resolve(false);
                    this.router.navigate(['login']);
                }

            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
            });
        });

    }
}
```

And then you can use in your routing like:

```
{
        path: 'awards-team',
        component: AwardsTeamComponent,
        canActivateChild: [RoleGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: 'admin',

            component: TeamComponentsAdminComponent,
            data: { roles: ['super-admin', 'admin', 'utente'] }
          },
          {
            path: 'user',

            component: TeamComponentsUserComponent,
            data: { roles: ['utente'] }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: This is a great way to pass values to the guard specific to the route. One recommendation I have is to use permissions instead of roles. It allows for easier control; permissions can change more often than roles do. Having said that, this setup can easily be modified to handle permissions.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions) library for controlling of permissions in your angular application. The benefits it will remove elements from DOM.
Example of loading permissions

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';

   constructor(private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
               private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const perm = ["ADMIN", "EDITOR"];

    this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm);

     this.http.get('url').subscribe((permissions) => {
       //const perm = ["ADMIN", "EDITOR"]; example of permissions
       this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(permissions);
    })
  }
}
```

Usage in templates

```
<ng-template [ngxPermissionsOnly]="['ADMIN']" (permissionsAuthorized)="yourCustomAuthorizedFunction()" (permissionsUnauthorized)="yourCustomAuthorizedFunction()">
    <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
 </ng-template>
<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']">
    <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
</div>

 <div *ngxPermissionsExcept="['ADMIN', 'JOHNY']">
   <div>All will see it except admin and Johny</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That looks nice. I will try it to integrate in my project. Thank you

Comment: @GregorDoroschenko Did you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

From my personal point of view, get permission from API is optimal solution for user rights.
In addition to checking permission by using `canActivate` attribute in Router, I like to use checking in navigation interceptor. Because it will keep the url when checking incorrect permissions instead of url localhost:42000/#/.../permission-denied

Here is my code:

In template

```
  <ng-template [ngIf]="!loading" [ngIfElse]="loadingView">
    <router-outlet *ngIf="canView"></router-outlet>
    <app-permission-denied *ngIf="!canView"></app-permission-denied>
  </ng-template>
  <app-loading #loadingView></app-loading>
```

In component

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  // import as RouterEvent to avoid confusion with the DOM Event
  Event as RouterEvent,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationCancel,
  NavigationError
} from '@angular/router'
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DataService } from '../core/service/data.service';
import { NotificationService } from '../core/service/notification.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit{

  // Sets initial value on first load
  loading: boolean = true;
  canView: boolean = false;
  haveErr: boolean = false;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,
    private router: Router,
    private _dataService: DataService,
    private titleService: Title,
    private _notificationService: NotificationService) {   
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(event)
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.canView = false;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

      //get permission user by pass function ID here...
      let functionId = this.getDataRouter(this.router, "function");

      if (functionId != null) {
        this._dataService.get('your_api_to_check_permission_with_functionId' + functionId).subscribe(
          (data) => {
            if (data && data.CanRead) {
              this.canView = true;
              let title = this.getDataRouter(this.router, "title");
              this.titleService.setTitle(title);
            } else {
              this.canView = false;
              this.titleService.setTitle('Permission denied');
            }
            this.loading = false
          }, (err) => {
            this._dataService.handleError(err);
          });
      } else {
        this.loading = false;
        this.canView = true;
        this._notificationService.printErrorMessage('Dev: please provide function Id to check permission');
      }

    }

    // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide in case a request fails
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
      this.loading = false
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false
    }
  }

  getDataRouter(router, name) {
    var root = router.routerState.snapshot.root;
    while (root) {
      if (root.children && root.children.length) {
        root = root.children[0];
      } else if (root.data && root.data[name]) {
        return root.data[name];
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

In router module

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'user', loadChildren: './system/user/user.module#UserModule', data: { function: "USER" } },

      { path: 'function', loadChildren: './system/function/function.module#FunctionModule', data: { function: "FUNCTION" } }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I would suggest you do it is using the **Router Guard** that Angular provides.

The following links could help get you started:

[router guard alligator](https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/)

[Router Guard Medium](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)