# Angular: Implement permission on component base on roles

Tags: angular, permissions, acl

I have an angular project. I want to implement a role-based permission for each user. each user has **userType** and **roles.**

The user type can be (admin, employer, job-seeker).

The roles for each user -> For example, the user (list, add, view, approve, verify email) ....etc.

Now what I am doing is :

While listing menu to the side bar. I have set roles for each menu it works fine.

The same thing I am doing with routes, I check on each route as describe it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45672249/9233289).

I am stuck on how to check (add, edit, list, and approve) action on the component.

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** [ngx-permission](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions) has done something, but it does not meet my requirement.

Comment: Add check for each action handler function i guess